# glVertexAttribPointer and stride parameter requirements

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, samsung-galaxy, stride

I've been having a weird bug on an *OpenGL*/*GLES* application I'm developing. On a certain device (*Samsung Galaxy S8*), it seems `glVertexAttribPointer` results in jibberish if the stride parameter is set to *18* bytes. The jibberish disappears if I add two bytes of padding to each component (*20* bytes in total).

Note that no `glGetError` is triggered regardless.

This bug does not occur on any other mobile device I've tested on, neither does it occur on my Windows computer running regular *OpenGL*.

My guess is that the stride is required to be a multiple four bytes, but I cannot seem to find any documentation verifying this.

Does anyone know if there are device specific requirements for the stride parameter?

(The 18 bytes consists of three *float32* followed by three *int16_t* = 3*4bytes + 3*2 bytes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the stride *required* by the specification to be aligned to 4 bytes? No.

Is there hardware that effectively has that requirement anyway? Yes, as evidenced by the fact that Vulkan has this requirement. So you should avoid misaligned data.

Comment: Thank you, especially for the Vulkan info

Comment: I wish the driver would give me a glGetError or something

Comment: @ViktorSehr: It *can't* give you an error because it doesn't violate the OpenGL specification.

Comment: I was thinking out loud I suppose :)